# Should the [bri] be burninated

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

A new[bri](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bri) tag was recently added to 8 questions and it appears to be about a "Belt and Road Initiative" in China. Personally I am of the mind that this tag is very unclear as to what it means and should be removed from all questions. The major problem is that it is too short which makes it unclear as to what it is supposed to be about.

However even if it was longer and spelled out I am not sure that it would be a valid tag.

Comment: Can people explain the downvotes? I don't see how bri is a useful tag. If it is a useful tag it should at least contain more then 3 letters to help people understand what it is.

Comment: Why are you *not sure that it would be a valid tag*? Tags [must be no longer than 35 characters](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) and `belt-and-road-initiative` is 24 characters. I agree that `bri` may be unclear.

Comment: @RickSmith Because a 3 letter acronym gives users no information about what the tag is about. I said I wasn't sure about the full word being valid but I do know that the 3 letter version isn't a good tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think [belt-and-road-initiative](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belt-and-road-initiative) should be the tag. Rather than *burninate* the [bri](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bri) tag (removal without replacement), it should be changed.

A user, unaware of [bri](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bri), and searching for questions about China's Belt and Road Initiative, would *more likely* enter `belt` for a tag search to see whether a tag exists and, failing that, would enter `belt and road` in the search bar to find related questions. Only then would they notice the [bri](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bri) tag.

Furthermore, I see no value in retaining [bri](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bri) as a synonym.

Comment: Done. I renamed the tag bri to belt-and-road-initiative. But it could still need a good usage guideline. I refrained from creating a synonym, because as a 3 letter acronym, "BRI" could very well become relevant for something completely different.